# Trying to import my helpers into a custom lib/class and suddenly I need a config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Real simple.

```
class Template

    def stuff_i_want
      stylesheet_link_tag('my_stylesheet')
    end

    class << self       
      include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
      include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
    end

end
```

And this returns..

```
undefined local variable or method `config' for Template:Class
from /Users/elephanttrip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@shasta/gems/actionpack-3.1.12/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helpers/stylesheet_tag_helpers.rb:137:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
```

From the `stylesheet_tag_helpers.rb` in Railtie :

```
    def stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)
      @stylesheet_include ||= StylesheetIncludeTag.new(config, asset_paths)
      @stylesheet_include.include_tag(*sources)
    end
```

Config isn't instantiated in that file anywhere, so I'm assuming its' required from somewhere else.. I have **no** idea where, or how.

Anyone know how to inject/pass a config into my helper? I've never needed to do this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're actually including your helpers into `Object` - and *then* defining your `Template` class. I've no idea why it's asking for config, but try putting the includes inside your class definition and see if the problem goes away.

You probably shouldn't be randomly including helpers into things over than your views though - that's not what they're for.

Comment: includes don't work inside the object. Putting them inside, the object won't know what those definitions are anymore. What makes you think this is random?

Comment: Really not sure what you mean - why wouldn't the objects know what the definitions are? If you include them outside the class definition, you're actually including them into the global object, not the class you're defining. Are you thinking of `require`?

Comment: Yep, I put includes inside class definition , and then it returns `NameError: undefined local variable or method `stylesheet_link_tag' for Template:Class`

Comment: Ah ok, I figured out how to put it in the class definition. Since its an unherited class I just needed to be put it in a `class << self` block. Still get the same error looking for that config though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `view_context` instead.

So instead of including the helper modules you can do this:

```
class Template

  def stuff_i_want
    view_context.stylesheet_link_tag('my_stylesheet')
  end
end
```

This should work fine.
And if you want to include you helpers then use the below code:

```
class Template
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def stuff_i_want
    stylesheet_link_tag('my_stylesheet')
  end
end
```

Ideally you should not include helpers in ur controllers as they are not intended for that.
Hope that helps

Comment: Hmm seems like you would have to include or require the helper that would offer `view_context`? Not sure what that is.. And if I put includes inside my class it won't recognize anymore what a `tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag` is anymore.

Comment: I've tried it and it works just fine for me. You don't have to require any helper to use `view_context`. See this [view_context](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context)